# Leaflet-DVF+ReactJs:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined(…)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-leaflet

When I'm trying to add layers `(L.MapMarker and L.ArcedPolyline)` in react component using `Leaflet-Dvf` library, I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined(…)
```

Leaflet-dvf reference: https://github.com/humangeo/leaflet-dvf

Tried with all possible dependencies but still same error. 
The same code in plain html working fine, error is coming only in React component.

**Below is the code:**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import '../../../node_modules/leaflet-dvf/dist/css/dvf.css';
    import stylingMap from "../scss/decisionmaking.scss";
    import { Map, Marker,Path } from 'leaflet-dvf';
    import '../../../node_modules/leaflet-polylinedecorator/leaflet.polylineDecorator.js';
    import '../../../node_modules/leaflet-dvf/src/leaflet.dvf.markers.js';
    const Decision = React.createClass({    
        componentDidMount() {
            this.map();
        },

        map() {
            var map = L.map('map').setView([2, 20], 2);    
            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">'
            }).addTo(map);    
        var marker = new L.MapMarker(new L.LatLng(20.593684, 78.96288), {
          radius: 10,

        });
        map.addLayer(marker);
var arcedPolyline = new L.ArcedPolyline([[20.593684, 78.96288],[37.09024,-95.712891]],{
          distanceToHeight: new L.LinearFunction([0, 5], [800, 200]),
          color: 'blue',
          weight: 2
      });
      map.addLayer(arcedPolyline);
            render: function() {
                return (
                    <div className="decisionmaking">
                    <div id='map' style={{height:500+"px", width:900+"px"}}></div>
                    </div>
            );
        }
        });
        module.exports = Decision;
```

Error Screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you including the leaflet source in index.html, using <script src=... >?

Comment: No. As I'm building my application in ReactJs so importing the dvf library in jsx file using import statement.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used React, but based on your import statements I can see one potential issue:  L.ArcedPolyline is defined in leaflet.dvf.lines.js and not in leaflet.dvf.markers.js.  It might make sense to import leaflet-dvf.js from the dist directory, since this contains everything?